# unable to display firebase data

Tags: angular, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3

I wanted to display record for the user who is already logged in.Here i have created bill module in this module i wanted to show bill list of logged in user i have successfully fetch the record but at the time of display on my html it show me error 'this is null'

[image]
bill.ts

```
public items = [];    ref.orderByChild("bill_eml").equalTo(window.sessionStorage.getItem("Sessioneml")).once("value", function(snapshot) {
                  console.log(snapshot.key);
                  console.log(snapshot.val());

                 this.items.push(snapshot.val());
                  console.log('item'+JSON.stringify(this.items));
                });
```

bill.html

```
<ion-list *ngFor="let item of items">
<ion-item (click)="viewItem(item)">
  <!-- <button ion-item *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="viewItem(item)">
  {{ item.description1 }}
</button> -->
  <p>{{item.bill_period}} </p>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: what is null here ?

Comment: "this" pointer is null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use arrow function .Arrow functions capture the `this` value of the enclosing context

Replace `.once('value', function () { ... })` with  following

```
public items = []; 
ref.orderByChild("bill_eml")
.equalTo(window.sessionStorage.getItem("Sessioneml"))
.once("value", (snapshot)=> {
        console.log(snapshot.key);
        console.log(snapshot.val());

        this.items.push(snapshot.val());
           console.log('item'+JSON.stringify(this.items));
      });
```

**Update**

Check out the updated answer

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Home</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

    <ion-content padding>
     <ion-list *ngFor="let item of objectKeys(items)">
    <ion-item>
    <b>{{ item }}</b>: {{ items[item].bill_eml }}

    </ion-item>
     </ion-list>
    </ion-content>



data=`
  [{
    "-L3glAc3XA9tnEIdjNtq": {
        "bill_due_date": "2018-01-25",
        "bill_eml": "demo@niyanta.co.in",
        "bill_flat": "345",
        "bill_id": "-L3glAc2ucb7Hfpnic23",
        "bill_name": "dfgh",
        "bill_period": "2018-02-01",
        "total": "4"
    },
    " -L40QW21pozAgTaYijh1": {
        "bill_due_date": "2018-01-29",
        "bill_eml": "demo@niyanta.co.in",
        "bill_flatno": "2",
        "bill_id": "-L40QW2-xMnuERXBLGxQ",
        "bill_name": "test",
        "bill_period": "2018-01-30",
        "total": "300"
    }
}]`
items;
objectKeys;
  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController) {
      this.objectKeys = Object.keys;
      this.items=JSON.parse(this.data)[0];
  }

}
```

Comment: _v.context.$implicit is null ?

Comment: Are you using ionic?

Comment: But it shows me only one record on view page and i have more then one record what to do?

Comment: in my console i retrieve the record what i wanted to dispaly. but when i bind that object to html it shows only single record

Comment: share your json response

Comment: [  {"-L3glAc3XA9tnEIdjNtq":{"bill_due_date":"2018-01-25","bill_eml":"demo@niyanta.co.in","bill_flat":"345","bill_id":"-L3glAc2ucb7Hfpnic23","bill_name":"dfgh","bill_period":"2018-02-01","total":"4"},"  -L40QW21pozAgTaYijh1":{"bill_due_date":"2018-01-29","bill_eml":"demo@niyanta.co.in","bill_flatno":"2","bill_id":"-L40QW2-xMnuERXBLGxQ","bill_name":"test","bill_period":"2018-01-30","total":"300"}}]

Comment: your response json contains only item in the array so that it's showing only one record

Answer (score 1):

Replace `.once('value', function () { ... })` with `.once('value', () => { ... })` (with arrow function). Function definition gets its own context to which `this` inside it refers. Arrow function will preserve the context.